# Добавить слэш в конец и отправить на обработчик URL htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Задачи: 
 1. Все URL запросы отправлять на обработчик index.php

 2. Добавлять в конец URL / (слэш)

 3. Исключения - папки JS, CSS, IMG

По отдельности
№1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

№2

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

А совместно уже не работает, подскажите как правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/[^/\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```